# Remove Specific Items from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on some code that takes an array of numbers and will remove any blanks and numbers with commas in them from the array.

```
for(var x = 0; z<employeeIDs.length; x++){
    if(employeeIDs[x] == ""){
        employeeIDs.splice(x, 1)
        x--
        continue
    }
    if(employeeIDs.includes(",")){
        employeeIDs.splice(x, 1)
        x--
    }
}
```

it seems to be working for the blanks but not the commas... Anyone see why that may be the case?

UPDATE:

I created another identical for loop and moved the 2nd if statement to that loop and things work as intended. I still don't know why it wouldn't work under the same loop?

Comment: Looks like a lot of work for something Array.filter was designed to help with

Comment: The second condition should be `employeeIDs[x].includes(",")`, not `employeeIDs.includes(",")`. And in for loop you have `z` instead of `x`

Comment: @adiga :O the z was a typo but that [x] was what I was missing! Sometimes all it takes is a 2nd set of eyes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are not checking if the item at index `x` `includes(",")`.

```js
const employeeIDs = ["544545", "5454", "", "54,5487"];

for(var x = 0; x <employeeIDs.length; x++){
    if(employeeIDs[x] == ""){
        employeeIDs.splice(x, 1)
        x--
    }
    if(employeeIDs[x].includes(",")){ // check for [x]
        employeeIDs.splice(x, 1)
        x--
    }
}

console.log(employeeIDs);
```

Another way you could accomplish this is by using the `filter` array method. Return the values that result as `truthy` (no empty values), and values that don't include `,`.

```js
const employeeIDs = ["544545", "5454", "", "54,5487"];

const result = employeeIDs.filter((id) => id && !id.includes(","));

console.log(result);
```